# I'm not sure where to ask a question about a Filezila, server and html document related issue?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

What Stack Exchange community is suitable for the following question?

> It's Pretty straightforward. When I download an HTML file from my
>   server it becomes corrupted with bunch of Chinese characters I didn't
>   put there. I don't know what's the problem, the encoding of the file
>   seems fine, and it shows up nicely in the browser.
>
> That is, unless I put the downloaded file back on the server, then
>   it's all screwed.

Answer (score 4):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) looks like a good match.

You are asking about the correct usage of a piece of software.

Do a search first, as this kind of problem could already have an answer there.

Answer (score -1):

[Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) might be a good bet, since it is *your* server. I'm not an expert at web servers and such, but if you are trying to handle a download between a server and client, and something screws up along the way, it may be on-topic there, if you're asking from the server perspective, I believe.